# Workaround for the WaitHandle.WaitAll 64 handle limit?

Tags: c#, multithreading, waithandle

My application spawns loads of different small worker threads via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` which I keep track of via multiple `ManualResetEvent` instances. I use the `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method to block my application from closing until these threads have completed.

I have never had any issues before, however, as my application is coming under more load i.e. more threads being created, I am now beginning to get this exception:

`WaitHandles must be less than or equal to 64 - missing documentation`

What is the best alternative solution to this?

**Code Snippet**

```
List<AutoResetEvent> events = new List<AutoResetEvent>();

// multiple instances of...
var evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
events.Add(evt);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    // do work
    evt.Set();
});

...
WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());
```

**Workaround**

```
int threadCount = 0;
ManualResetEvent finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

...
Interlocked.Increment(ref threadCount);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    try
    {
         // do work
    }
    finally
    {
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount) == 0)
        {
             finished.Set();
        }
    }
});

...
finished.WaitOne();
```

Comment: If and when you move to .NET 4 take a look at [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx). It wraps up the counting in a tidy package.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a variable that keeps track of the number of running tasks:

```
int numberOfTasks = 100;
```

Create a signal:

```
ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Decrement the number of tasks whenever a task is finished:

```
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numberOftasks) == 0)
{
```

If there is no task remaining, set the signal:

```
    signal.Set();
}
```

Meanwhile, somewhere else, wait for the signal to be set:

```
signal.WaitOne();
```

Comment: @dtb: So rather than maintaining a list of MRE's just maintain the count and after each thread finishes just decrement (and trigger if count reaches 0)?

Comment: Exactly. MRE's are somewhat heavyweight, so the 64 limit has a reason. Try to avoid too many of them :-)

Comment: Excellent, jst one more thing. I don't exactly know the number of threads the list is built up dynamically is it safe to increment the count inside each new thread before any work is performed and then decrement at the end?

Comment: No don't increment the numberOfTasks in the thread. That could lead to a situation where the numberOfTasks reaches 0 but not all tasks have been started yet. Increment the numberOfTasks right before your call to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, so it's guaranteed that all tasks have been started before you call signal.WaitOne(). Use Interlocked.Increment to increment the numberOfTasks.

Comment: @dtb: I was worried incase what happens if I increment the numberOfTasks and for (whatever reason) the thread fails to start, this means the signal would never get set or numberOfTasks would never get decremented? Not really sure of the likelyhood of this happening tho....

Comment: Any code in your task (`// do work`) can throw an exception. So you should make sure that, if an exception is thrown, the numberOfTasks is properly decremented (`try ... finally`). Don't worry that your UserWorkItem might not be executed - it will. Eventually.

Comment: @dtb: Actually just did that! haha will post the code I intend to use, thanks.

Comment: So increment the numberOftasks before the QueueUserWorkItem, but where  would you decrement that? I am guessing inside the thread?

Answer (score 44):

Starting with .NET 4.0, you have two more (and IMO, cleaner) options available to you.

The first is to use the [`CountdownEvent` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx).  It prevents the need of having to handle the incrementing and decrementing on your own:

```
int tasks = ...; /* however many tasks you're performing */

// Dispose when done.
using (var e = new CountdownEvent(tasks))
{
    // Queue work.
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => {
        // Do work
        ...

        // Signal when done.
        e.Signal();
    });

    // Wait till the countdown reaches zero.
    e.Wait();
}
```

However, there's an even more robust solution, and that's to use the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), like so:

```
// The source of your work items, create a sequence of Task instances.
Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i =>
    // Create task here.
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        // Do work.
    }

    // No signalling, no anything.
).ToArray();

// Wait on all the tasks.
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Using the `Task` class and the call to [`WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) is much cleaner, IMO, as you're weaving less threading primitives throughout your code (notice, no wait handles); you don't have to set up a counter, handle incrementing/decrementing, you just set up your tasks and then wait on them.  This lets the code be more expressive in the *what* of what you want to do and not the primitives of *how* (at least, in terms of managing the parallelization of it).

.NET 4.5 offers even more options, you can simplify the generation of the sequence of `Task` instances by calling the [static `Run` method on the `Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051.aspx):

```
// The source of your work items, create a sequence of Task instances.
Task[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i =>
    // Create task here.
    Task.Run(() => {
        // Do work.
    })

    // No signalling, no anything.
).ToArray();

// Wait on all the tasks.
Tasks.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Or, you could take advantage of the [TPL DataFlow library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) (it's in the `System` namespace, so it's official, even though it's a download from NuGet, like Entity Framework) and use an [`ActionBlock<TInput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx), like so:

```
// Create the action block.  Since there's not a non-generic
// version, make it object, and pass null to signal, or
// make T the type that takes the input to the action
// and pass that.
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<object>(o => {
    // Do work.
});

// Post 100 times.
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)) actionBlock.Post(null);

// Signal complete, this doesn't actually stop
// the block, but says that everything is done when the currently
// posted items are completed.
actionBlock.Complete();

// Wait for everything to complete, the Completion property
// exposes a Task which can be waited on.
actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Note that the `ActionBlock<TInput>` by default processes one item at a time, so if you want to have it process multiple actions at one time, you have to set the number of concurrent items you want to process in the constructor by passing a [`ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.aspx) instance and setting the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx):

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<object>(o => {
    // Do work.
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });
```

If your action is truly thread safe, then you can set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelsim` property to [`DataFlowBlockOptions.Unbounded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.unbounded.aspx):

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<object>(o => {
    // Do work.
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataFlowBlockOptions.Unbounded
});
```

The point being, you have fine-grained control over *how* parallel you want your options to be.

Of course, if you have a sequence of items that you want passed into your `ActionBlock<TInput>` instance, then you can link an [`ISourceBlock<TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160369.aspx) implementation to feed the `ActionBlock<TInput>`, like so:

```
// The buffer block.
var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();

// Create the action block.  Since there's not a non-generic
// version, make it object, and pass null to signal, or
// make T the type that takes the input to the action
// and pass that.
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(o => {
    // Do work.
});

// Link the action block to the buffer block.
// NOTE: An IDisposable is returned here, you might want to dispose
// of it, although not totally necessary if everything works, but
// still, good housekeeping.
using (link = buffer.LinkTo(actionBlock, 
    // Want to propagate completion state to the action block.
    new DataflowLinkOptions {
        PropagateCompletion = true,
    },
    // Can filter on items flowing through if you want.
    i => true)
{ 
    // Post 100 times to the *buffer*
    foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)) buffer.Post(i);

    // Signal complete, this doesn't actually stop
    // the block, but says that everything is done when the currently
    // posted items are completed.
    actionBlock.Complete();

    // Wait for everything to complete, the Completion property
    // exposes a Task which can be waited on.
    actionBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
```

Depending on what you need to do, the TPL Dataflow library becomes a *much* more attractive option, in that it handles the concurrency across *all* the tasks linked together, and it allows you to be very specific about *just* how parallel you want each piece to be, while maintaining proper separation of concerns for each block.

Answer (score 18):

Your workaround is not correct. The reason is that the `Set` and `WaitOne` could race if the last work item causes the `threadCount` to go to zero *before* the queueing thread has had to chance to queue *all* work items. The fix is simple. Treat your queueing thread as if it were a work item itself. Initialize `threadCount` to 1 and do a decrement and signal when the queueing is complete.

```
int threadCount = 1;
ManualResetEvent finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);
...
Interlocked.Increment(ref threadCount); 
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate 
{ 
    try 
    { 
         // do work 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount) == 0) 
        { 
             finished.Set(); 
        } 
    } 
}); 
... 
if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount) == 0)
{
  finished.Set();
}
finished.WaitOne();
```

As a personal preference I like using the `CountdownEvent` class to do the counting for me.

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
...
finished.AddCount();
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate 
{ 
    try 
    { 
         // do work 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
      finished.Signal();
    } 
}); 
... 
finished.Signal();
finished.Wait();
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to dtb's answer you can wrap this into a nice simple class.

```
public class Countdown : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ManualResetEvent done;
    private readonly int total;
    private long current;

    public Countdown(int total)
    {
        this.total = total;
        current = total;
        done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Signal()
    {
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref current) == 0)
        {
            done.Set();
        }
    }

    public void Wait()
    {
        done.WaitOne();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ((IDisposable)done).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to  dtb's answer when we want to have callbacks.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.TestMRE();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

class Main
{
    CalHandler handler = new CalHandler();
    int numberofTasks =0;
    public void TestMRE()
    {

        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Outer Loop is :" + j.ToString());
            ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            numberofTasks = 4;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                CalHandler.count caller = new CalHandler.count(handler.messageHandler);
                caller.BeginInvoke(i, new AsyncCallback(NumberCallback),signal);
            }
            signal.WaitOne();
        }

    }

    private void NumberCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        AsyncResult asyncResult = (AsyncResult)result;

        CalHandler.count caller = (CalHandler.count)asyncResult.AsyncDelegate;

        int num = caller.EndInvoke(asyncResult);

        Console.WriteLine("Number is :"+ num.ToString());

        ManualResetEvent mre = (ManualResetEvent)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref numberofTasks) == 0)
        {
            mre.Set();
        }
    }

}
public class CalHandler
{
    public delegate int count(int number);

    public int messageHandler ( int number )
    {
        return number;
    }

}
```

Comment: please ignore naming convention , its just quick code.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void WaitAllExt(WaitHandle[] waitHandles)
{
    //workaround for limitation of WaitHandle.WaitAll by <=64 wait handles
    const int waitAllArrayLimit = 64;
    var prevEndInd = -1;
    while (prevEndInd < waitHandles.Length - 1)
    {
        var stInd = prevEndInd + 1;
        var eInd = stInd + waitAllArrayLimit - 1;
        if (eInd > waitHandles.Length - 1)
        {
            eInd = waitHandles.Length - 1;
        }
        prevEndInd = eInd;

        //do wait
        var whSubarray = waitHandles.Skip(stInd).Take(eInd - stInd + 1).ToArray();
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(whSubarray);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solved it by simply paginating the number of events to wait without much performace lost, and it's working perfectly on production environment. Follows the code:

```
        var events = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        // code omited

        var newEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        events.Add(newEvent);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c => {

            //thread code
            newEvent.Set();
        });

        // code omited

        var wait = true;
        while (wait)
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.Take(60).ToArray());
            events.RemoveRange(0, events.Count > 59 ? 60 : events.Count);
            wait = events.Any();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. Here is the "events" is a list of ManualResetEvent. The size of the list can be greater than 64 (MAX_EVENTS_NO).

```
int len = events.Count;
if (len <= MAX_EVENTS_NO)
    {
        WaitHandle.WaitAll(events.ToArray());
    } else {
        int start = 0;
        int num = MAX_EVENTS_NO;
        while (true)
            {
                if(start + num > len)
                {
                   num = len - start;
                }
                List<ManualResetEvent> sublist = events.GetRange(start, num);
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(sublist.ToArray());
                start += num;
                if (start >= len)
                   break;
           }
   }
```