# ThreadPool - WaitAll 64 Handle Limit

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to bypass the the wait64 handle limit that .net 3.5 imposes

I have seen this thread : [Workaround for the WaitHandle.WaitAll 64 handle limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702545/workaround-for-the-waithandle-waitall-64-handle-limit)

So I understand the general idea but I am having difficulty because I am not using a delegate but rather

I am basically working of this example :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28VS.80%29.aspx

This link http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-the-threadpool 
is similar but again the int variable keeping track of the tasks is a member variable.

Where in the above example would I pass the threadCount integer?
Do I pass it in the callback method as an object? I think I am having trouble with the callback method and passing by reference.

Thanks Stephen,

That link is not entirely clear to me.

Let me post my code to help myself clarify:

```
for (int flows = 0; flows < NumFlows; flows++)
{
ResetEvents[flows] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
ICalculator calculator = new NewtonRaphson(Perturbations);
Calculators[flows] = calculator;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(calculator.ThreadPoolCallback, flows);
}
resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Where would I pass in my threadCount variable. I assume it needs to be decremented in calculator.ThreadPoolCallback?

Comment: Sorry I believe I meant "threadCount" from the first link.

Comment: Minor technical point: the 64-handle limit is imposed by the Win32 API, not .NET 3.5. So, every program on Windows has the same limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using multiple wait handles to wait for the completion of multiple work items in the `ThreadPool`. Not only is it not scalable you will eventually bump into the 64 handle limit imposed by the `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method (as you have done already). The correct pattern to use in this situation is a counting wait handle. There is one available in the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) download for .NET 3.5 via the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28VS.100%29.aspx) class.

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
for (int flows = 0; flows < NumFlows; flows++) 
{ 
  finished.AddCount();
  ICalculator calculator = new NewtonRaphson(Perturbations); 
  Calculators[flows] = calculator; 
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    (state) =>
    {
      try 
      { 
        calculator.ThreadPoolCallback(state); 
      }
      finally 
      { 
        finished.Signal(); 
      }
    }, flows);
} 
finished.Signal();
finished.Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous method might be easiest:

```
int threadCount = 0;
for (int flows = 0; flows < NumFlows; flows++)
{
    ICalculator calculator = new NewtonRaphson(Perturbations);
    Calculators[flows] = calculator;

    // We're about to queue a new piece of work:
    //    make a note of the fact a new work item is starting
    Interlocked.Increment(ref threadCount);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        delegate
        {
            calculator.ThreadPoolCallback(flows);

            // We've finished this piece of work...
            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref threadCount) == 0)
            {
                // ...and we're the last one.
                // Signal back to the main thread.
                resetEvent.Set();
            }
        }, null);
}
resetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: If you look at the links provided you can see I am trying to avoid using anonymous methods.

Comment: I don't see why you're avoiding anonymous methods -- are you targetting the .NET 1.0 or 1.1 runtimes?

Comment: There is an ever so subtle bug here. The `WaitOne` and the `Interlocked.Decrement` will race causing `WaitOne` to return too early if the last work item has been queued *and* completed before the next iteration of the loop has a chance to `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: The solution is really simple though. Treat the queueing thread as if it were a work item. Increment `threadCount` before the loop and decrement after the loop and signal exactly as the work items would.