# How to Monitor C# Threads from another Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, threadpool, terminate

I have several Threads running in a ThreadPool in my WPF App. I need to monitor them, possibly from another Thread to find out if all of those Threads have terminated. 
How would I be able to achieve this.

For simplicity, my usage scenario is:

1. Click a button
2. Start several Threads in a ThreadPool.
3. Start another Thread to Monitor those in a ThreadPool
4. Lock UI of WPF App.
5. Release Lock when the Thread in step 3 sets a Global value to indicate that Threads started in (2) have terminated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for the WaitHandle.WaitAll 64 handle limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702545/workaround-for-the-waithandle-waitall-64-handle-limit)

Comment: Despite the very diffeent title this is about the same problem and has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem at hand is actually too localized. I had to adopt to an Ad Hoc approach to fit in with the initial flawed design.

My approach was to simply increase a counter whenever a Thread is started and decrease the value of the counter when that Thread terminates. To watch over the value of counter, I initiated another Thread simply to monitor the value of counter. Maybe not an elegant approach, but seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the threads in the threadpool in  an array. When you want to wait for the pool threads to exit, use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` to wait for the threads to complete.

Comment: @Henk Hoterman: I assumed he would write his own thread pool as he wanted control over the threads. If using the built in pool, then the whole idea seams flawed.