# Handle more than 64 thread at the same time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

I was reading a tutorial about [Thread pooling in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/3dasc8as.aspx). There was an example with Fibonacci calculations:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1

Public Class Fibonacci
    Private _n As Integer
    Private _fibOfN
    Private _doneEvent As ManualResetEvent

    Public ReadOnly Property N() As Integer
        Get
            Return _n
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property FibOfN() As Integer
        Get
            Return _fibOfN
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal doneEvent As ManualResetEvent)
        _n = n
        _doneEvent = doneEvent
    End Sub

    ' Wrapper method for use with the thread pool.
    Public Sub ThreadPoolCallBack(ByVal threadContext As Object)
        Dim threadIndex As Integer = CType(threadContext, Integer)
        Console.WriteLine("thread {0} started...", threadIndex)
        _fibOfN = Calculate(_n)
        Console.WriteLine("thread {0} result calculated...", threadIndex)
        _doneEvent.Set()
    End Sub

    Public Function Calculate(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
        If n <= 1 Then
            Return n
        End If
        Return Calculate(n - 1) + Calculate(n - 2)
    End Function

End Class


<MTAThread()> 
Sub Main()
    Const FibonacciCalculations As Integer = 9 ' 0 to 9

    ' One event is used for each Fibonacci object
    Dim doneEvents(FibonacciCalculations) As ManualResetEvent
    Dim fibArray(FibonacciCalculations) As Fibonacci
    Dim r As New Random()

    ' Configure and start threads using ThreadPool.
    Console.WriteLine("launching {0} tasks...", FibonacciCalculations)

    For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
        doneEvents(i) = New ManualResetEvent(False)
        Dim f = New Fibonacci(r.Next(20, 40), doneEvents(i))
        fibArray(i) = f
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf f.ThreadPoolCallBack, i)
    Next

    ' Wait for all threads in pool to calculate.
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents)
    Console.WriteLine("All calculations are complete.")

    ' Display the results.
    For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
        Dim f As Fibonacci = fibArray(i)
        Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci({0}) = {1}", f.N, f.FibOfN)
    Next
End Sub

End Module
```

I've start this module and it works correctly and this just handle 9 calculations:

```
Const FibonacciCalculations As Integer = 9
```

I've increase that limits, but this can just handle up to 63 calculations. From 64th calculation exception is raised that said:

> waithandle must be less than 64

I would this application will handle N calculations. A good idea could be set a cap to pool of threads (for instance: 6). The N calculations will be handle using at most 6 thread at once. How could I edit the code to handle this removing the `waitHandle` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The winapi restriction on the number of handles you can wait on at the same time is a pretty hard one.  It is just not necessary, you'll get the exact same outcome if you wait for each individual one:

```
' Wait for all threads in pool to calculate.
For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
    doneEvents(i).WaitOne()  
Next
```

And note how you can now combine this with the next loop, making your program more efficient since you overlap the calculation with the display.  So you really want to favor this instead:

```
' Display the results.
For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
    doneEvents(i).WaitOne()
    Dim f As Fibonacci = fibArray(i)
    Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci({0}) = {1}", f.N, f.FibOfN)
Next
```

Comment: In this way I've two for loops. If I don't need to display result, the second loop with just contains the WaitOne() function. What should I do if I don't need to display a result? I really need to for loop with one loop just for WaitOne()?

Comment: If you don't display or use the result then the logical thing to do is to not start the thread in the first place.  Please use the Ask Question button if you have another question and thought about it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for X task completions where X>63, use a countdown: ONE atomic int and ONE MRE. Initialize the int to [no. of tasks], start your tasks and wait on the MRE with WaitForSingleObject() / WaitOne().  When a task is complete, it atomically decrements the int.  Any task, running on any thread, that decrements it to zero signals the MRE.

In fact, use this mechanism for X<63 :)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your system cannot support more than 64 objects in WaitHandle, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx

You can find a workaround for this issue here:

[Workaround for the WaitHandle.WaitAll 64 handle limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702545/workaround-for-the-waithandle-waitall-64-handle-limit)

However, as the other answers state, you probably would not gain from having this many threads anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real advantage to using that many threads on a machine with 4 cores or 2 cores.  You really, ideally, only want the same number of threads as you have cores.

If you have more you start losing on parallelism as threads need to be context switched out to let others run. You also may run into contention issues, depending on how your algorithm is written.

The point of a threadpool is really to tell your system to *maximally* use some number of threads and leave the rest up to the system to figure out what is best.

Comment: You can get contention issues with two threads on a 16-core box - it's not just a problem with an overloaded system.