# What's the proper use of WaitOne() function

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

I was experimented some Thread pool examples. I've started from [Fibonacci example on MSDN web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/3dasc8as.aspx), but [this wasn't suitable for more than 64 calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103084/handle-more-than-64-thread-at-the-same-time), so i've resolved with this code:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Public Class Fibonacci
        Private _n As Integer
        Private _fibOfN
        Private _doneEvent As ManualResetEvent

        Public ReadOnly Property N() As Integer
            Get
                Return _n
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property FibOfN() As Integer
            Get
                Return _fibOfN
            End Get
        End Property

        Sub New(ByVal n As Integer, ByVal doneEvent As ManualResetEvent)
            _n = n
            _doneEvent = doneEvent
        End Sub

        ' Wrapper method for use with the thread pool.
        Public Sub ThreadPoolCallBackMar(ByVal threadContext As Object)
            Dim threadIndex As Integer = CType(threadContext, Integer)
            Console.WriteLine("thread {0} started...", threadIndex)
            _fibOfN = Calculate(_n)
            Console.WriteLine("thread {0} result calculated...", threadIndex)
            _doneEvent.Set()
        End Sub

        Public Function Calculate(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
            If n <= 1 Then
                Return n
            End If
            Return Calculate(n - 1) + Calculate(n - 2)
        End Function

    End Class


    <MTAThread()>
    Sub Main()
        Const FibonacciCalculations As Integer = 65

        ' One event is used for each Fibonacci object
        Dim doneEvents(FibonacciCalculations) As ManualResetEvent
        Dim fibArray(FibonacciCalculations) As Fibonacci
        Dim r As New Random()

        ' Configure and start threads using ThreadPool.
        Console.WriteLine("launching {0} tasks...", FibonacciCalculations)

        For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
            doneEvents(i) = New ManualResetEvent(False)
            Dim f = New Fibonacci(r.Next(20, 40), doneEvents(i))
            fibArray(i) = f
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf f.ThreadPoolCallBackMar, i)
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("All calculations are complete.")

        For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
            doneEvents(i).WaitOne()
            Dim f As Fibonacci = fibArray(i)
            Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci({0}) = {1}", f.N, f.FibOfN)
        Next

        Console.Read()
    End Sub
End Module
```

The use of `WaitOne()` instead of `WaitAll()` resolve the problem but the question is: If I don't need to display the results then I don't need neither the second loop, but... without the second loop where I've to put the `waitOne()` function?

Comment: Switch to using the TPL to collapse your 50 lines of threading into 5. Use `Parallel.For`. Or do you insist on doing it the old way?

Comment: Right now old way, but new way is really interesting...

Comment: This problem can be solved by applying something called "horse sense".  A very important programmer skill.  If you don't want to display the result then don't start the thread.  You thus don't need WaitOne() either.

Comment: What do you mean by: don't start the thread? In my case I need to call a webservice, and since the response could be quite slow, i want make more than one call at once and I don't have a response from WS (that's why I don't need to print a result). I just have to know when every thread is completed....

Comment: If you don't want to wait until the threads are complete ... then don't wait! Don't call the function WaitOne/WaitAll. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: I need to wait until ALL threads are complete. Alas, I can't use WaitAll function if there are more than 64 calculations (see the linked question in the main post). Is the for loop (repeated n times) with WaitOne the only way to know when ALL threads are completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does essentially this:

```
// start a bunch of threads to do calculations

Console.WriteLine("All calculations are complete."); // This is a lie!

// Wait for the threads to exit
```

The primary problem here is that the calculations *are not complete* when you make that call to `Console.WriteLine`. Well, they *might* be complete, but you don't know unless you've waited on the event to see that it's signaled.

The purpose of `WaitOne` is to tell you if the calculation has completed. Your code should be written like this:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
        doneEvents(i) = New ManualResetEvent(False)
        Dim f = New Fibonacci(r.Next(20, 40), doneEvents(i))
        fibArray(i) = f
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf f.ThreadPoolCallBackMar, i)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("All calculations are started. Waiting for them to complete.")

    For i As Integer = 0 To FibonacciCalculations
        doneEvents(i).WaitOne()
        Dim f As Fibonacci = fibArray(i)
        Console.WriteLine("Fibonacci({0}) = {1}", f.N, f.FibOfN)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("All calculations are complete.")
```

You *must* check the event to know that the calculation is complete.

Now, if you don't need to know if the calculation is complete, then there's no need for the `WaitOne` at all. And if you're not going to wait on the event, then there's no real need to *have* the event, is there? Although one wonders why you're going to do a calculation and then not use the result.

Comment: Thank you, for patience.
I appreciate :)