# Request terminates prematurely in .NET MVC 4, probably due to the multi-threading work

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

In the action method, I'm trying to generate separate report for each contract, zip all the reports and send the zip file back to client.

To improve the performance, I use ***ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem*** method to multi-threading the tasks. To wait for all the work done before sending back the zip file,  ***WaitHandle.WaitAll*** method is used here.

It works well with small datasets. For example, one 9-contract dataset took 1.5 mins for the whole process.  But for a large dataset that has 86 contracts, the response comes back immediately after I send the request. It's a invalid zip file. I can tell the threads are still running to generate reports. But  ***WaitHandle.WaitAll*** and anything after are not executed at all, as far as I see.

Any idea why?

```
public void GenerateReport(ReportParams parameters)
{
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;  // for large files
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        const string filename = "test.zip";
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + filename);

        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4);
        Log.Info("Starting the batch report");
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            var doneEvents = new ManualResetEvent[parameters.Contracts.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Contracts.Length; i++)
            {
                var contract = parameters.Contracts[i];
                doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                    ExportReport,
                    new ThreadInfo
                    {
                        Contract = contract,
                        Zip = zip,
                        DoneEvent = doneEvents[i]
                    });
            }

            WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
            zip.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        }

        Log.Info("Finishing the batch report");
    }

protected void ExportReport(object obj)
{
        var info = obj as ThreadInfo;
        var reportDoc = new ReportDocument();
        Log.Info("Thread Id {0} processing contract {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, info.Contract);
        SetPath(reportDoc);
        SetDbInfo(reportDoc);
        LoadParameter(reportDoc);

        reportDoc.SetParameterValue("Contract", info.Contract);
        reportDoc.ExportToDisk(
                ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,
                string.Format(@"C:\TempFile\{0}.pdf", info.Contract));
        info.Zip.AddFile(string.Format(@"C:\TempFile\{0}.pdf", info.Contract));
        Log.Info("Thread Id {0} finishing contract {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, info.Contract);
        reportDoc.Dispose();
        info.DoneEvent.Set();          
}
```

Comment: adding extra `!` to your title is not going to get you help any faster.

Comment: If one of the threads crashes out you could see something like this.

Comment: I have checked the logs and all the threads complete successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. ***WaitHandles*** must be less than or equal to 64.

For solution, please see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142341/Solved-The-number-of-WaitHandles-must-be-less-than or [Workaround for the WaitHandle.WaitAll 64 handle limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702545/workaround-for-the-waithandle-waitall-64-handle-limit)